How to locate image on a large image with different target size
I am trying to use pyautogui.locateOnScreen(btn, confidence=0,8, grayscale=True) to locate image, but if the search image has a different size, it cannot be able to locate.
In my case, I want to locate the confirm button on screen. I take the shortcut of button on site A (a small size), and locate it on site B, but it didn't work.
I want to detect the position of this button on different websites. Except for the size, all other parts are the same, including color, shape, and button text.
I tried cv2.matchTemplate(scr_img, search_image, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) but it didn't work either.
Is there another way?

with pyautogui.locateOnScreen
from PIL import Image

confirm_btn_img = Image.open("./img/confirm_btn.png")
try: 
    l, t, w, h = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(confirm_btn_img, confidence=0.8, grayscale=True)
except Exception as e:
    print("Not Found")

with cv2.matchTemplate:
import cv2
import numpy as np

confirm_btn_img2 = cv2.imread("./img/confirm_btn.png", 0)
yautogui.screenshot()
big_image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(big_image), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

res = cv2.matchTemplate(big_image, confirm_btn_img2, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8

loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

print("loc====", loc)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(big_image, pt, (pt[0] + confirm_btn_img2.shape[1], pt[1] + confirm_btn_img2.shape[0]), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('Detected', big_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

can be found:

cannot be found:

targe image:

example code:
import cv2
import numpy as np

confirm_btn_img2 = cv2.imread("./test/ok.png", 0)
big_image = cv2.imread("./test/can_found_tpl.png", 0)

res = cv2.matchTemplate(big_image, confirm_btn_img2, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.8

loc = np.where(res >= threshold)

print("loc====", loc)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(big_image, pt, (pt[0] + confirm_btn_img2.shape[1], pt[1] + confirm_btn_img2.shape[0]), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('Detected', big_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Hey, to help you further we would need some more information. Can you please edit your post to include your src and template image? As well as the python code, altough you already have that there

[mre] required. -- this isn't a new task, nor are your troubles new. please browse past questions. they likely come with answers.

I think Template Matching with Scaling can help, if scale variation is not very much random..
And you can also try Feature Matching.
For Feature Matching you can try this

import cv2
import numpy as np

def feature_matching(big_image_path, template_image_path):
    big_image = cv2.imread(big_image_path, 0)
    template_image = cv2.imread(template_image_path, 0)

    orb = cv2.ORB_create()

    keypoints1, descriptors1 = orb.detectAndCompute(template_image, None)
    keypoints2, descriptors2 = orb.detectAndCompute(big_image, None)

    bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
    matches = bf.match(descriptors1, descriptors2)
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x: x.distance)

    if matches:
        img_matches = cv2.drawMatches(template_image, keypoints1, big_image, keypoints2, matches[:10], None, flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS)
        cv2.imshow("Matches", img_matches)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

        # Get the coordinates of the matched keypoints
        point = keypoints2[matches[0].trainIdx].pt
        print(f"Found at: {point}")
    else:
        print("Not Found")

And for using Scale variations with Template matching, this can help

import cv2
import numpy as np

def multi_scale_template_matching(big_image_path, template_image_path, scales):
    big_image = cv2.imread(big_image_path, 0)
    template_image = cv2.imread(template_image_path, 0)
    h, w = template_image.shape

    found = None

    for scale in scales:
        resized = cv2.resize(template_image, (int(w * scale), int(h * scale)))
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(big_image, resized, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

        if found is None or max_val > found[0]:
            found = (max_val, max_loc, scale)

    if found:
        max_val, max_loc, scale = found
        top_left = max_loc
        bottom_right = (top_left[0] + int(w * scale), top_left[1] + int(h * scale))
        cv2.rectangle(big_image, top_left, bottom_right, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.imshow('Detected', big_image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print(f"Found at: {top_left}")
    else:
        print("Not Found")

def generate_scales(min_scale, max_scale, step_size):
    scales = np.arange(min_scale, max_scale + step_size, step_size)
    return scales

min_scale = 0.5
max_scale = 1.5
step_size = 0.1

scales = generate_scales(min_scale, max_scale, step_size)
multi_scale_template_matching('big_image.png', 'confirm_btn.png', scales)


